# Fetch ROWID in mimer-sql

Tags: rowid, mimer-sql

How to fetch ROWID / ROWNUM in mimer-sql? I need too update table based on ROWID, so need to fetch rowid and update the specfic rowid only.

Comment: Mimer doesn't have the rowid concept. If you want to update a specific row, you will have to identify the row to be updated somehow, for example using the primary key value.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (no images.) [mcve].